# Super Basic Server-Client Application in C

Tags: c, sockets, client

i am trying to make a server client application using sockets in C.
Server and client compile just fine but they dont seem to connect with each other and i don't understand why (i just started learning about sockets).
My OS is SunOs 5.10.

This is my code for the server : http://pastebin.com/TbLCG5BA

This is my code for the client : http://pastebin.com/SvAtyyi7

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You really don't describe the problem. What did you expect to happen? What happened or didn't happen that made you think they weren't connecting?

Comment: Thank you for your time.
If you see in the servers code there is a printf that is supposed to be executed after the connection. 
The problem has been fixed though thanks to svk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both your client and your server you're calling bzero() on your structures *after* you initialize them. That means you first fill in your information, and then you set everything to zero (losing all your information).

Set everything to zero first (thus correctly initializing fields you won't use). Then initialize your structures.

Comment: That fixed it. 
Thank you svk for your well explained answer.